# Como transformar uma lista genérica em uma lista de um objeto especifico?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, expressões-lambda, .net-core

Basicamente tenho duas classes Miniaturas e Users (Onde na tabela miniatura eu tenho o UserId para vincular ambas). E gostaria de exibir o Users.email + Miniaturas.* (todas as infos de miniaturas) na listagem da view.

Então fiz o seguinte, criei um ViewModel para ter o Users e Miniaturas juntos, dessa forma:

```
  public class MiniaturasViewModel
    {
        public Miniatura Miniatura { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }
```

Em seguida, fiz o Join (que traz uma lista genérica aparetemente):

```
string UserId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
         
            var JoinUserMiniaturas = _context.Miniaturas
                        .Join(_context.Users, miniatura => miniatura.UserId, user => user.Id, (miniatura, user) => new { miniatura, user }).ToList();



            //MiniaturasViewModel ViewModel = new MiniaturasViewModel();
            //ViewModel.Miniatura = JoinUserMiniaturas[0].miniatura;
            //ViewModel.User = JoinUserMiniaturas[0].user;
            //var ListViewModel = new List<MiniaturasViewModel> { ViewModel };
            return View(ListViewModel);
```

Porém, gostaria que minha view recebesse uma lista de um tipo especifico:

```
@model IEnumerable<HotWheelers.Models.MiniaturasViewModel>


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.Email)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Miniatura.Fabricante)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Miniatura.Marca)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Miniatura.Modelo)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Miniatura.AnoModelo)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Miniatura.AnoLote)
                </th>
                @*<th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Miniatura.LinkImg)
                </th>*@
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Miniatura.Fabricante)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Miniatura.Marca)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Miniatura.Modelo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Miniatura.AnoModelo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Miniatura.AnoLote)
            </td>
            @*<td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Miniatura.LinkImg)
            </td>*@
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Miniatura.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Miniatura.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Miniatura.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Porém, este código apresenta falha, pois o tipo que o ".toList()" traz é diferente do esperado pela view.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei conseguindo depois de quebrar a cabeça um pouco (e pra variar a resposta foi meio obvia). Bastava definir como montar usando o meu model (new MiniaturasViewModel(miniatura, user)), da seguinte forma:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            string UserId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);

            var miniaturas = await _context.Miniaturas
                        .Join(_context.Users, miniatura => miniatura.UserId, user => user.Id, (miniatura, user) => new MiniaturasViewModel(miniatura, user))
                        .Where(m => m.Miniatura.UserId == UserId)
                        .ToListAsync();

            return View(miniaturas);
        }
```